# $expr not working as expected on array of sub documents in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am building an aggregation and want to find documents based on some values in an array of subdocuments. When I hardcode the query like the below, it works as expected:

```
{
  $match: {
    'subDocumentArray.createdAt': {$gt: ISODate('2023-06-30T14:00')}
   }
}
```

When I attempt to use an $expr statement in order to utilise the '$$NOW' variable, I get no results.

```
{
   $match: {
            $expr : {
                $gte : [
                    '$subDocumentArray.createdAt',
                    {
                        $dateTrunc : {
                            date : "$$NOW",
                            unit : "month",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
         }
}
```

If i change the above to use a top level property on the document, the query works as expected.

```
{
   $match: {
            $expr : {
                $gte : [
                    '$createdAt',
                    {
                        $dateTrunc : {
                            date : "$$NOW",
                            unit : "month",
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
         }
}
```

Can someone explain why this isn't working and what changes (if any) I need to make?

We are using MongoDB v6

Comment: The $expr is for an expression operator, and $gt inside $expr works differently than normal, so it will consider `$subDocumentArray.createdAt`  an array of dates, and single date can't match the condition with an array of dates in $expr operator.

Comment: @turivishal I am trying to avoid unwinding the subdocument array as the collection is quite large

Comment: It is possible without unwinding, there is an answer already, but instead, I would suggest you check the condition by external input instead of using $$NOW, array operators in $match with $expr stage is a little more expensive than a normal query in terms of speed and memory use.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from @turivishal's comment, one option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {$expr: {
        $gt: [
          {$size: {$filter: {
              input: "$subDocumentArray",
              cond: {
                  $gt: ["$$this.createdAt", {$dateTrunc: {date: "$$NOW", unit: "month"}}]
                }
          }}},
          0
        ]
  }}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l0KWkMpkgCd)